# how to click the link in cypress

Tags: cypress

How to click this link with cypress?

```html
<a href="#" aria-disabled="false" class="button ">
  <span class="icon icon-chevron-down " aria-hidden="true">
  </span>
  <span class="screen-reader-only">
    chevron-down_icon
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's pretty easy, the documentation of Cypress would help you as wel: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click.html#Command-Log . But I'll help you too. I did the assumption that this is the only hyperlink on the page:

```js
cy.get('a')
  .click()
```

If it is not the only one you could try to get the link via the class (assuming that the class is unique on the page):

```js
cy.get('.button')
  .click()
```

If both assumptions are invalid, the class is not unique and there are multiple hyperlinks, you can try this:

```js
cy.get('a')
  .eq(1)
  .click()
```

The 1 of `eq()` is the number of the element. The first element is 0, the second 1, the third 2, etc etc

**Edit** I saw you updated your original post, so I'll another option. You could use the other elements that are available:

```js
cy.get('.icon-chevron-down')
  .parent()
  .click()
```

Comment: thank you! It worked with:
`cy.get('.icon-chevron-down')
  .parent()
  .click()`

Comment: Good to hear that, please accept the answer in that case :)