# How to click link in Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, href, cypress

I want to click on below link in a page with several other links like this one.
I have tried cy.get() with a number of alternative ways. I also tried cy.contains('Content 6') but received an error.

```
<div class="column">
    <a href="/admin/contents/109">
        <div class="ui segment">
            <div class="ui center aligned header">
                Content 6
                <div class="sub header">Add description to content packages
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

This was my final solution:

```
cy.get('a[href*="admin/contents"]').contains('Content 6').click()
```

I found the solution on this page and with help from user called Udo: [https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-element’s-text-contents](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-element%E2%80%99s-text-contents)

The href code gives more example on how to handle this problem then other examples for same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to click the link in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594334/how-to-click-the-link-in-cypress)

Comment: I've tested this earlier but did not get I t right. Don't know what to replace ".icon-chevron-down" with  cy.get('.icon-chevron-down')
  .parent()
  .click()'''

Comment: Sounds like your issue is not clicking on the element but finding the actual element. Can you post how you're selecting it at the moment ? And is that 'contents/109' dynamic ?

Comment: Do you have any control over the code? To add your own id or test-id? I see you found a solution. I myself would like a definitive id that won't change I can get to.

Comment: How do I find my id or test-id? Can you please also specify what you are asking for? @Maccurt

Comment: If you can add to the code, compile it, push it to your environment I would suggest you put an attribute (id or test-id) on your element so you don't have to look it up by the content which could change. for instance that anchor link, I would add <a id="admin-link> then you search by cy.get("#admin-link")

Comment: Is id found in my code such as <div id="root">? Thank you for your tip but I will use my href-link for know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to "get" the correct element to click on. in your case it could be handled like this:

```js
// find the link with href attribute containing "admin/contents" and click it
cy.get('a[href*="admin/contents"]').click()
```

Comment: It seems like your example finds the actual page but there's no connection to the link itself. You are right about that 'Contents/109' is dynamic. But my test adds a new content Called Content 6 every time it runs. So the question know maybe is how to find that text.

Comment: Check my solution above. Thanks for your help :)